# How do I renew the SSL certificate for my ios push notification provider?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, certificate

A bit under a year ago, a teammember who has now left built an iphone app which is on the app store, and an ios push notification daemon which sends it notifications.  Today, the daemon started spitting out SSL certificate errors - it seems the daemon's certificate has expired.

I've got the username and password of the developer account, and I've logged into the provisioning portal to create a new certificate.  If I go to manage the App ID of our older apps that we no longer support, I see this:

[image: console with configure button]

But if I manage the App ID of the one I'm trying to renew, I see this:

[image: console without configure button]

Why isn't there an option for me to generate a new push SSL certificate for this app?  How do I renew the push daemon's ssl certificate without it?

Will we need to rebuild and resubmit the app?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If the certificate has expired, you must generate and download the new certificate, remove older certificates, and install the new on the server.

Resubmit the app is not necessary, just install the certificate on the server, no changes happens on client apps.

Comment: Great, thanks - how do I generate the new certificate?  I can't see an option to do so in the provisioning portal.

Comment: Revoke the expired certificate and configure the certificate with the signing request file.

Comment: Will revoking the certificate make the 'configure' button appear?

Comment: Note, you will need to regenerate all Provisioning Profiles that included this certificate.

Comment: Tim, I am afraid it is not true, I had expired ssl APNs cert. Created new one, uploaded to our PHP APNs server and it started to work right off, no need to generate any provisioning profile.

Comment: if I select Configure option on "Generate a new Production Push SSL certificate before your current one expires" will that expire the old certificate automatically if it's not expired?

Comment: No the current will not expire, the two are valid

Comment: @VilémKurz correct, no need to regenerate the provisioning profile.

Comment: but what if i create a new push ssl certf instead of renewing the older one.. with a new key value pair in the certf now old version of my app won't receive the push right?