# iOS -Urbanairship push notification on production not working

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to implement push notification for an iPhone app using Urbanairship.
So, when I'm using ad hoc build (which is a different cert file), when I go to settings > notification, it is showing up there just fine.

However, with the app version that I put up on iTunes, I don't see my app name when I go to settings > notification. Neither did I get the popup that says, "Hey this app is going to send push notification, allow or disallow".

The only thing I can think off that might cause it is that, while in review, the SSL certificate expired. We have renewed that, but still no luck.

According to this link, [How do I renew the SSL certificate for my ios push notification provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779668/how-do-i-renew-the-ssl-certificate-for-my-ios-push-notification-provider), I don't have to resubmit. Or do I?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and issue a Production push cert. Then upload that to urban airship, and switch everything to use that cert for production mode.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I didn't upload the file to Urbansirship. D'oh!